# Получить цены с другого сайта и присвоить переменным. Как сократить код?

Tags: php, php-curl

Всё конечно работает, но чувствую, что здесь много лишнего кода.
Мне кажется `foreach` здесь лишний.

Подскажите пожалуйста, скорее всего здесь можно обойтись без кучи циклов?
Нужен не просто вывод цен, это было бы проще,
в дальнейшем переменные с ценами будут использоваться в расчетах.

```
function get_web_page( $url )
    {
      $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";
    
      $ch = curl_init( $url );
    
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // возвращает веб-страницу
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);           // не возвращает заголовки
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   // переходит по редиректам
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");        // обрабатывает все кодировки
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  // useragent
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // таймаут соединения
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        // таймаут ответа
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);       // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа (не много ли!?)
    
      $content = curl_exec( $ch );
      $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
      $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
      $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
      curl_close( $ch );
    
      $header['errno']   = $err;
      $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
      $header['content'] = $content;
      return $header;
    }
    
    $url = 'https://металлград.com/catalog/truba-profilnaya/';
    $data = get_web_page($url); // загружаем результат с помощью нашей функции
    
    
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML( $data['content'] );
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
    
    $_20_20_15 = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]");
     $_20_20_2 = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]");
    $_25_25_15 = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]");
    
    foreach( $_20_20_15 as $obj ) {$_20_20_15 = $obj->nodeValue;}
    foreach( $_20_20_2 as $obj ) {$_20_20_2 = $obj->nodeValue;}
    foreach( $_25_25_15 as $obj ) {$_25_25_15 = $obj->nodeValue;}
    
    echo '20*20*1.5 - '.$_20_20_15.'<br/>';
    echo '20*20*2 - '.$_20_20_2.'<br/>';
    echo '25*25*1,5 - '.$_25_25_15.'<br/>';
```

Comment: а что, тебе только 3 цены надо?

Comment: нет, гораздо больше, и с разных страниц

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предпочитаю регулярки для парсинга хтмл, с помощью DomDocument() тоже можно перебирать циклом, а не вручную набирать цену каждого товара.

```
function get_web_page($url) {
    $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // возвращает веб-страницу
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);           // не возвращает заголовки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   // переходит по редиректам
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");        // обрабатывает все кодировки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  // useragent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // таймаут соединения
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        // таймаут ответа
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);       // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа (не много ли!?)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);       // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа (не много ли!?)

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
    $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $header['errno'] = $err;
    $header['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}


$url = 'https://металлград.com/catalog/truba-profilnaya/';
$html = get_web_page($url)['content']; // загружаем результат с помощью нашей функции

//3 кармана
preg_match_all('~<tr data-id="[^"]+">\s*<td>(.+?)</td>\s*<td>(.+?)</td>\s*<td>(.+?)</td>~isu', $html, $finded);

$table = [];
foreach ($finded[1] as $k => $v) {
    $table[$k] = array_merge([strip_tags($v)], [$finded[2][$k]], [is_numeric($finded[3][$k]) ? $finded[3][$k] : '-']);
}

var_dump($table);

//array (size=55)
//  0 => 
//    array (size=3)
//      0 => string 'Труба Профильная  10 Х 10 Х 1,2 Х.к.' (length=55)
//      1 => string '6.00' (length=4)
//      2 => string 'ожидаем' (length=14)
//  1 => 
//    array (size=3)
//      0 => string 'Труба Профильная  15 Х 15 Х 1,5' (length=48)
//      1 => string '6.00' (length=4)
//      2 => string '57' (length=2)
//  2 => 
//    array (size=3)
//      0 => string 'Труба Профильная  20 Х 20 Х 1,5' (length=48)
//      1 => string '6.00' (length=4)
//      2 => string '78' (length=2)
```